# Request Hangs in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a brand new express API application and for some reason when I run it (the command is `node src/index.js`) both requests hang and there is never a response. I have been able to nail it down to the `app.use(express.json)` line as the culprit. When it is commented out the requests seem to work, but then I do not get access to request body.

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.json);

app.post("/api/user/register", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Ok");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("API is up and running!");
});
```

The contents of my package.json file is as follows:

```
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

I am currently running node version 13.2.0. Any suggestions on what to try next? (I'm new to node so any help would be appreciated)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's supposed to be `app.use(express.json());` not `app.use(express.json);`

Comment: o god. I did the same thing. 42 minutes wasted, LOL.  thank you so much!

Comment: same, 2 years later, wasted almost half an hour.